# extendedDataTable - height doesn't work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

So, like the title says in my case height of the extendedDataTable doesn't work, so my table also doesn't scroll because all rows are shown. I'm using richfaces4.0-final version. So here is my piece of code:

```
        <rich:extendedDataTable
            value="#{advancedSearchView.criteria}" var="criteria"
            height="50px"
            selection="#{advancedSearchView.selection}" id="table"
            selectionMode="single">
            <rich:column id="criteria_row" filterBy="#{criteria}" filterEvent="onkeyup" width="500px">
                <h:outputText value="#{criteria}" />
            </rich:column>
        </rich:extendedDataTable>
```

AdvancedSearchView is request scoped bean, and criteria is an array of Strings.

I hope that is enough information. Thank you in advance. A would really appreciate if someone gives me an answer, because I'm struggling with this for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [RichFaces 4 VDL (View Declaration Language) documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/vdldoc/), the [`<rich:extendedDataTable>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/vdldoc/rich/extendedDataTable.html) component does not support the `height` attribute at all.

Your functional requirement is however understood. You want to render the extended datatable with a height of 50px and make the table body scrollable. You need to achieve this using the usual CSS means by `style` attribute which can take inline CSS declarations, or by the `styleClass` attribute which can take CSS classes, like as on almost every other JSF HTML component.

So, with `style`

```html
<rich:extendedDataTable ... style="height: 50px;">
```

or, with `styleClass` (which is also the more recommend practice; separate style from markup)

```html
<rich:extendedDataTable ... styleClass="criteria">
```

and this piece in a CSS file which you include by `<h:outputStylesheet />`:

```css
.criteria {
    height: 50px;
}
```